# Insert Event in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am comparatively new to Entity Framework and apologize if this question is asked before. I searched for it but didn't find any thing.

My scenario is that I have an Entity Table which is as follow

### Entity

ID 
CreateDate
ModifiedDate
LastActionByUser

And some tables, for example Subjects

### Subject

ID, Name, EntityID

Now, whenever my code inserts any thing in the dependent table such as Subject, I want to create a record in Parent Table (Entity in this case), get its id and pass it on to EntityID field of the dependent table.

I have almost 50 tables with the same scenerio, so I want to do it in a generic way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this, Entity Framework will do this for you automatically if you have the relationships setup correctly.  Instead of inserting an Entity, you add the Entity to a collection of Entity objects that the Subject holds.  This key is then automatically updated when you commit changes.